# Unable to debug WCF service message

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

I've got a Visual Studio 2008 solution with a WCF service, and a client.

When I run my client, and call a method from my service I get a message saying "Unable to automatically debug 'Home.Service'. The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled on the server."

I've googled around, and have tried the following.

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

has been added in app.config on both the client and the server.

I have also made sure that the project is being compiled in Debug mode.

What else could be causing this message?

Edit: Added more info based on feedback questions

- It is using wsHttpBinding
- I have set

  ```
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  ```
- I am using

  ```
  var service = new HomeReference.HomeServiceClient();
  service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  ```

Unfortunately the error shows up the first time I call a method on my Service. I can dismiss the messagebox, and the application continues working. Any Exceptions thrown on the server at not propagated back to the client though (I assume it should?)

Comment: What type of binding are you using when you try to debug your WCF service?

Comment: I haven't done any changes to the Binding, and it is set to wsHttpBinding.

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF service?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at tracing depending on the problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case the problem turned out to be a mismatch between security settings on client and server. I was using a custom binding like this:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="AuthorisedBinaryHttpsBinding" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
      <!-- this next element caused the problem: -->
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
      </security>
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="1000000"
          maxArrayLength="655360000" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

When I removed the security element that I've highlighted above the problem with the "Unable to automatically debug" message went away.

To solve the problem I first turned on [WCF tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx). This showed me that WCF was throwing a **MessageSecurityException**:

> Security processor was unable to find
>   a security header in the message. This
>   might be because the message is an
>   unsecured fault or because there is a
>   binding mismatch between the
>   communicating parties.   This can
>   occur if the service is configured for
>   security and the client is not using
>   security.

That pointed me to look at the Binding settings on the client side. It turned out that I hadn't added the required security element to my custom binding there. Since I was doing this through code, I needed the following (note the 3rd line):

```
  var binding = new CustomBinding(
      binaryEncoding,
      SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement(),
      new HttpsTransportBindingElement { MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxMessageSize, });
```

As to why Visual Studio was showing that error, I've no idea - looks to me to be a bug.

Comment: I wont post this as an answer because its not, but after hours of work getting a solution to open and compile on 2 different machines, one gets this error, the other does not. It is not a configuration mismatch. This WCF stuff is nice and all, but way not finished or mature.

Comment: Something Microsoft did isn't finished or mature? I'm sure that's not possible

Comment: Did you remove security from client or server?

Answer (score 40):

I was fighting with this exact same error for over an hour and low and behold I restarted VS2008 and it magically fixed itself. Give it a try as it might save you some time.

Comment: This fixed it for me after hours of googling/stackoverflowing

Comment: This also fixed the problem for me (I too spent about an hour trying to understand WTF was happening ..)

Comment: Same here! And The tracing surely didn't show any warning or error

Comment: This also worked for me. I noticed that before restarting there was an odd `IOException` reported in the Output window, and after the restart it was gone. I guess something was causing the `IOException` which then made VS2010 want to debug it, but it couldn't - probably for the same reason it happened in the first place. Odd.

Comment: I wish to understand why these issues still exist after years of bug reporting. The first report was in 2008! Maybe shame on me that I still have to work on VS2010 for my customer.

Comment: Worked with VS2012 too.

Answer (score 8):

Automatically attaching to a service has the following limitations:

- The service must be part of the Visual Studio solution you are debugging.
- The service must be hosted. It may be part of a Web Site Project (File System and HTTP), Web Application Project (File System and HTTP), or WCF Service Library project. WCF Service Library projects can be either Service Libraries or Workflow Service Libraries.
- The service must be invoked from a WCF client.
- Debugging must be enabled with the following code in the app.config or Web.config file:

  ```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  ```

See [Limitations on WCF Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx)

In addition, if both projects (client and service) are in the same solution but will run in different processes (for example if you are using your local IIS Server for development and are running your web application on a **different application pool** than the service it consumes), you may need to enable "**Multiple startup projects**" for the solution (on Solution Properties -> Startup Project) so that the debugger can attach to both.

To avoid the service browser window to show up every time you debug, you may set the "Start Action" (on service project properties) to "Don't open a page. Wait for request from external application."

This is from personal experience and may help others.

Answer (score 7):

The other reason you might see this error (and I believe is the case for me) is if you're running in 64bit Windows. Apparently Visual Studio doesn't have any x64 debugger support.

You can work around this by changing the Platform Target for the consuming application:

Project Properties -> Build -> Change "Platform Target" to "x86".

Unfortunately this won't work for me as I'm trying to run in the Windows Azure Development AppFabric which seems to require everything to run in 64bit mode!

Comment: Visual Studio has had x64 debugger support since VS2005, so I don't think that in itself was the problem

Comment: Yep, I think this must've been a red herring with the Azure SDK. I can't recall the exact issue or error that led me to post the above. Oh well - apologies for the misleading info.

Comment: @SamuelJack while VS indeed can debug x64 apps for some reason the WCF service auto attach feature does not work if the client app is using x64. But I see no problem in setting the Debug build to use "x86" while the Release build still stays on AnyCPU. Using VS2010 + WPF people will not even come across this problem since these apps will be automatically x86.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem. I changed  in both client & service config files like

Compilation debug is set to true.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
    <serviceBehaviors>

  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
```

For debugging purposes?

Edit : nevermind, I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes, I've actually set that one to True. Forgot to mention that. I assume it's only needed on the serversider app.config, since it isn't included in the clientside app.config.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and it turns out to have been due to Windows Authentication not being enabled on the IIS site/virtual directory.

Have you tried setting the authentication mode to Integrated instead of Anonymous?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8a5axew(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your web service web.config ensure that compilation debug is set to true.
That should fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem turned out to be something completely different. I had changed the name of an operation on the webservice and forgot to update the client. For some reason this resulted in the "Unable to automatically debug ..." error.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be that the same port number is used in IISExpress and IIS. If you are developing a WCF application in Visual Studio and IISExpress and then install the same application on your local IIS make sure not to use the same port number in IIS and IISExpress. Using the same port number will lead to this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2017. After deleting the hidden .vs folder in the root of the solution folder, I was able to debug again.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of code after you create your service reference in your client.

```
MyWCFService.IService _proxy = new MyWCFService.IService();
_proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help either.

Comment: The issue posted by the OP is not dependent on the ClientCredential settings. What if a developer were using Certificate credentials...how would the above assist in that situation???