# MessageSecurityException, how to fix different client and server time?

Tags: c#, wcf

I get this error when trying to connect to a server using WCF and my client time is different from server time:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or 
   incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner 
   FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> 
   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security 
   for the message.
```

My question is, are there any solutions to this problem? Or is this really is a limitation for wcf services? 
I can't turn off the security of my binding since it is in specification that it should be secured.

I'm using TransportWithMessageCredential for my binding security mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `FaultContract` on your interface methods along with `OperationContract`. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx).

Also your fault contract object needs to have the same namespace as the Action namespace.

Try debugging the service. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315210/unable-to-debug-wcf-service-message).