# Visual Studio Enable Web Service Debug

Tags: c#, web-services

I have 1 windows form and 1 web service project. When I try to debug, I get the following error. I changed the debug operation to true on web congfig, but still cannot debug. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

Comment: Do you start both projects? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. still can't run in debug mode.

Comment: Strange. Maybe the various tips here help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315210/unable-to-debug-wcf-service-message